# Cypress/npm: Is there a way to combine --env inside a script with an appended passed-in variable?

Tags: javascript, tags, cypress

I understand the manual way to get npm to do what I want to do. It would be:

```sh
npx cypress open --env configFile=integration,tags=api
```

but say I have a script in my package.json file which is:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:open:int": "npx cypress open --env configFile=integration"
  }
}
```

and I want to add another environment variable to my script *sometimes* - is there a way to do this? I've tried variations like:

```sh
npm run cypress:open:int -- --env tags=api
```

but these errors inside Cypress as I have 2x --env flags in my command

Comment: Is this a cypress tag ? why not just `--tag "api"`

Comment: What error do you get?